# Parsing the output to verify the column value

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have the following output from the `docker ps` command:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS  PORTS     NAMES
e1d52c0adee7        share-platform:6000/share-platform:1.0.96-windowsservercore      "powershell -Commandâ€¦"   3 months ago        Up 2 weeks              share-platform
ad6a8e2c7fd0        prism:6000/prism-platform:1.0.1078-windowsservercore   "powershell -Commandâ€¦"   3 months ago        Up 2 months                    9080/tcp                                  prism-platform
efd847643e86        mongo:6000/mongo:3.2-windowsservercore             "mongod --smallfilesâ€¦"   3 months ago        **Restarting (100) 2 weeks ago**   27017/tcp                                  mongo
3d8ab9b5c36e        share:6000/share-app:1.0.153-windowsservercore     "powershell -Commandâ€¦"   3 months ago        Up 2 months             share-app
dc4b1053d9da        prism-app:6000/prism-app:1.0.4183.1-windowsservercore      "powershell -Command¦"   3 months ago        Up 2 months                                                               prism-app
2a38e006f85f        core:6000/welcome:1.0.241.1-windowsservercore         "powershell -Command¦"   3 months ago        Up 2 months
```

I am trying to loop through the status column in the output and if there is status other than `UP`, I want to echo it.

I tried exporting it to csv and then using the `Import-Csv`. What is expected is since MongoDB status is not `Up`, I want it to echo it to the screen like "Mongo is not Up" (getting name from the `NAMES` column).

Actual result from the script is blank.

```
docker ps | out-file D:\temp\PAW_ps.csv
$csv = Import-Csv D:\Temp\PAW_ps.csv
foreach ($row in $csv)
{
$name = $row.NAMES
$status = $row.STATUS
if ($status -ne "UP")
{
  echo "The process $name is not Up"
}




 Output of docker ps | gm
  PS C:\Windows\system32> docker ps | gm


   TypeName: System.String

   Name             MemberType            Definition                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   ----             ----------            ----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object 
   ICloneable.Clone()                                                                                                                                                                   
   CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), 
   int CompareTo(string strB), int IComparable.CompareTo(System.Object obj), int IComparable[string].CompareTo(string other)                                                             
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)                                                                                                                                                                                               
CopyTo           Method                void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex, int count)                                                                                                                                         
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool EndsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, cultureinfo culture)                                                       
Equals           Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string value), bool Equals(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool IEquatable[string].Equals(string other)                                                
GetEnumerator    Method                System.CharEnumerator GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator[char] IEnumerable[char].GetEnumerator()                                         
GetHashCode      Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                                                                                         
GetType          Method                type GetType()                                                                                                                                                                                                            
GetTypeCode      Method                System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(), System.TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode()                                                                                                                                                 
IndexOf          Method                int IndexOf(char value), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex, int count), int IndexOf(string value), int IndexOf(string value, int startIndex), int IndexOf(string value, i...
IndexOfAny       Method                int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int count)                                                                                       
Insert           Method                string Insert(int startIndex, string value)                                                                                                                                                                               
IsNormalized     Method                bool IsNormalized(), bool IsNormalized(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)                                                                                                                                   
LastIndexOf      Method                int LastIndexOf(char value), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex, int count), int LastIndexOf(string value), int LastIndexOf(string value, int startIndex), int Las...
LastIndexOfAny   Method                int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int count)                                                                           
Normalize        Method                string Normalize(), string Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)                                                                                                                                     
PadLeft          Method                string PadLeft(int totalWidth), string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)                                                                                                                                          
PadRight         Method                string PadRight(int totalWidth), string PadRight(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)                                                                                                                                        
Remove           Method                string Remove(int startIndex, int count), string Remove(int startIndex)                                                                                                                                                   
Replace          Method                string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar), string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)                                                                                                                              
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count), string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count, System.StringSpl...
StartsWith       Method                bool StartsWith(string value), bool StartsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool StartsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, cultureinfo culture)                                                 
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)                                                                                                                                            
ToBoolean        Method                bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                              
ToByte           Method                byte IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                 
ToChar           Method                char IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                 
ToCharArray      Method                char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)                                                                                                                                                      
ToDateTime       Method                datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                         
ToDecimal        Method                decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                           
ToDouble         Method                double IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                             
ToInt16          Method                int16 IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                               
ToInt32          Method                int IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                 
ToInt64          Method                long IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(cultureinfo culture)                                                                                                                                                                     
ToLowerInvariant Method                string ToLowerInvariant()                                                                                                                                                                                                 
ToSByte          Method                sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                               
ToSingle         Method                float IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                              
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider), string IConvertible.ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                        
ToType           Method                System.Object IConvertible.ToType(type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                   
ToUInt16         Method                uint16 IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                             
ToUInt32         Method                uint32 IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                             
ToUInt64         Method                uint64 IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                             
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(cultureinfo culture)                                                                                                                                                                     
ToUpperInvariant Method                string ToUpperInvariant()                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()                                                                                                                                                                       
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)                                                                                                                                                                                   
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)                                                                                                                                                                                 
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                              
Length           Property              int Length {get;}
```

Comment: Can you share the CSV file content? Just to understand what columns you actually are seeing.

Comment: Could you please try and run `docker ps | Get-Member` and update your question with the results?

Comment: I have added the output of docker ps | gm to Original message. Thank you

Comment: Did you get things working?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to export and import the data that you are trying to work with.

A quick pseudo code example:

```
docker ps | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.STATUS -ne "UP") {
        Echo "The process $($_.NAMES) is not up"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Motz. The status column has Status "Up Uptime" like "Up 2 Months" "Up 2 Weeks". So I tweaked your script to change it like this: if ($_.STATUS -notlike "Up"). But the output is empty  The process  is not up
      The process  is not up
      The process  is not up
      The process  is not up

Comment: Could you please run the `docker ps | gm` and share the output of that with us? I guess that it should be `-notlike "*Up*"` if what you say is true...

Comment: I have added the output of docker ps | gm to Original message. Thank you

Comment: From the output you shared, it seems that the output is just a string. I need to see if I can get access to a docker image that works, so I can test things out.

Comment: Sure, Thank you so much.